# NestedScrollView with webView only scrolling NestedScrollView

Tags: android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

Below is my code to handle the correct behaviour of my apps actionBar/toolbar/tabBar and nestedScrollView with a ViewPager (webView) inside it. The ViewPager is basically a normal webView.

Everything works fine except my ViewPager can't be scrolled vertically. Only the NestedScrollView is being scrolled. I want the same behaviour as the Facebook app, if you scroll the newsfeed (webView) the tabBar moves the toolbar out of vision vertically.

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     tools:context=".ui.activity.FragmentContainer"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     >
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         >
>                 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>                     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>                     app:theme="@style/M.Toolbar"
>                     app:popupTheme="@style/M.Toolbar.PopupTheme"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>                     >
>                 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
>         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>             android:id="@+id/tabs"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             app:tabMode="scrollable"
>             android:visibility="gone"
>             android:background="@color/background"
>             app:background="@color/background"
>             />
>
>     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
>     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>         android:fillViewport="true"
>         >
>
>     <com.m.ui.util.EdgeScrollViewPager
>         android:id="@+id/viewpager"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>         android:visibility="visible"
>         >
>
>     </com.m.ui.util.EdgeScrollViewPager>
>
>     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
>
> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

So in order to be able to scroll my viewPager (webView) I added a new class which extends webView:

> public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {
>
> ```
>     public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>     }
>
>     public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>         super(context, attrs);
>     }
>
>     public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
>         requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
>         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
>     }
> }
> ```

This solves the problem with the viewPager (webView) which becomes scrollable. BUT, the NestedScrollView becomes static and refuses to scroll the tabBar/toolbar vertically. So I am stuck with either scrolling the webView OR the tabBar-toolbar. How do I make both viewPager(webView) and NestedScrollView (tabBar/toolbar) scrollable at the same time ?

**My webView**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <FrameLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@android:color/white">
>
>     <com.m.ui.base.TouchyWebView
>         android:id="@+id/web_webview"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>         android:visibility="visible" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/web_loadingview"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:visibility="gone"
>         android:layout_gravity="center">
>
>         <ProgressBar
>             style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:indeterminate="true"
>             android:visibility="visible"
>             android:layout_gravity="center"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Regards

Answer (score 7):

Please, try this code:

```java
class NestedScrollWebView constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet): WebView(context, attrs), NestedScrollingChild2 {

    private var lastMotionY = 0
    private var nestedYOffset = 0
    private val scrollOffset = IntArray(2)
    private val scrollConsumed = IntArray(2)
    private val childHelper = NestedScrollingChildHelper(this)

    init {
        isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event == null) return false

        val motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
        val currentY = event.y.toInt()

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                nestedYOffset = 0
                lastMotionY = currentY
                startNestedScroll(View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                var deltaY = lastMotionY - currentY

                if (dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, deltaY, scrollConsumed, scrollOffset)) {
                    deltaY -= scrollConsumed[1]
                    motionEvent.offsetLocation(0f, scrollOffset[1].toFloat())
                    nestedYOffset += scrollOffset[1]
                }

                lastMotionY = currentY - scrollOffset[1]

                val oldY = scrollY
                val newScrollY = Math.max(0, oldY + deltaY)
                val dyConsumed = newScrollY - oldY
                val dyUnconsumed = deltaY - dyConsumed

                if (dispatchNestedScroll(0, dyConsumed, 0, dyUnconsumed, scrollOffset)) {
                    lastMotionY -= scrollOffset[1]
                    motionEvent.offsetLocation(0f, scrollOffset[1].toFloat())
                    nestedYOffset += scrollOffset[1]
                }

                motionEvent.recycle()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> stopNestedScroll()

            else -> { }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun startNestedScroll(axes: Int, type: Int) = childHelper.startNestedScroll(axes, type)

    override fun stopNestedScroll(type: Int) = childHelper.stopNestedScroll(type)

    override fun hasNestedScrollingParent(type: Int) = childHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent(type)

    override fun dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray?, offsetInWindow: IntArray?, type: Int) =
            childHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow, type)

    override fun dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed: Int, dyConsumed: Int, dxUnconsumed: Int, dyUnconsumed: Int, offsetInWindow: IntArray?, type: Int) =
            childHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow, type)

}
```

and in the layout leave only WebView:

```xml
<com.widget.NestedScrollWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 6):

It works for me,
 add This line to NestedScrollview in XML File.

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

then
    set webview height wrap_content.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: That works! I upvoted because that's what I experimented just 30 seconds before reading this, and Android Studio was installing right when I was reading this. Funny! Nice find! Catch is to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with the Webview.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with `setFillViewport (true)`
A piece of my code

```
 NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.nest_scrollview);
    scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```

And inside the fragment I had a listView where I sat `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` .. Fixed the scrolling issue